# How to add parameters in android http POST?

Tags: android

friends,

i am trying to upload file to php server using following tutorial
http://getablogger.blogspot.com/2008/01/android-how-to-post-file-to-php-server.html

i dont know how to add parameters like

> userid="12312";sessionid="234"

in it.

any one guide me how to achieve this?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

#### How to make an http POST and adding parameters.

how to add parameters? you must have something like.

```
// Add your data  
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", "12312"));  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sessionid", "234"));  
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

This is a complete method:

```
public void postData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/myexample.php");

try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "stackoverflow.com is Cool!"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    
   } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi,  if suppose I've to pass the strings "id" and "stringdata" as a child of another string how can I proceed. (i.e)
"{"parentNode":{"id":"12345","stringdata": "stackoverflow.com is Cool!"}}

In this can you please mention how to pass the values to "parentNode"