# What is the difference between setParams() and setEntity() with regards to HttpGet/HttpPost/*Delete/PUT methods in Android?

Tags: android, httprequest, apache-httpcomponents

I am trying to set request parameters, some tutorials say to use setentity, however setentity is not present for HttpDelete. How can I get a uniform method to work with all 4 request methods? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Well, according to what you corrected, you may need to use query strings in the request URI. The parsing has to be done manually, but it's not exceptionally hard.

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) and [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) to know how query strings work.

Comment: are we talking about parameters for requests here? i might have made a mistake, it might not be header, just parameters for a request that is usually sent with post requests.

Comment: i looked at setHeader() method, and it is not that. it should be something that would accept a list of named value pair. like a dictionary.

Comment: I'm not sure if you read the Method Definitions section of the RFC (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html), here it's stated that the DELETE method does not need anything besides the URI of the resource to be deleted

Comment: query strings even for POST method?

Comment: your method seems to be entirely different from this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288823/how-to-add-parameters-in-android-http-post , given that setEntity exists for POST/PUT, and GET uses query strings, i'm just wondering about DELETE.

Comment: Well the DELETE method only requires the location of the resource to be deleted, so I don't know why would you need a key value pair 'like' query for a DELETE method, but you may do a GET first get the desired element with the query string needed, and use the response entity to DELETE the resource. Right now it's what it comes to my head...