# fail to send two parameters in http - post call

Tags: android

I trying to send two parameters to some server. 
the server is responding to http-post call and the two parameters are 
     Int
     Some Enum ( that i sending as string )

I want to send the parameters as json:

```
        StringEntity t = new StringEntity("{ \"intValParam\":-100 , \"enumParam\":\"enumValueAsString\" }" , "UTF-8");

        httppost.setEntity(t);

        httppost.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
```

The response that i get is 400 ( bad request )

** There is one more method that i can call that need to have one parameter ... only the int - and this method is working good - so this is not problem from the bad connection or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not try to add your parameters like that. Either use the method `setParams` from httpPost or use NameValuePair entities and encode them in your request, like that :

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2); 
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", "12312"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sessionid", "234")); 
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

code taken [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288823/how-to-add-parameters-in-android-http-post).