# Http post variables

Tags: android

I'm trying to get data from server by setting parameters in Http post method (like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288823/how-to-add-parameters-in-android-http-post))

It works great when params are directly set in url, but when i try to set parameters using `setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs))` server returns blank answer (like i haven't defined any variable). Here is my `doInBackground()` code :

```
     String inMsg = "";
        String url = "xxx";

         HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
         DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
         BufferedReader input = null;
         HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

         List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("retrieve", "test"));
         try {

             post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
             HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
             HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

          if (isCancelled())
             {
              publishProgress(CANCELLED);
              return (null);
             }

          input = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader (entity.getContent(), "iso-8859-1"), 8);

          StringBuilder inptemp = new StringBuilder();
          while ((inMsg = input.readLine()) != null)
          {
              inptemp.append(inMsg + "\n"); 
          }

          publishProgress(SUCCESS);

          if (isCancelled())
             {
              publishProgress(CANCELLED);
              return (null);
             }

          inMsg = "";
          inMsg = inptemp.toString();


          Log.w("params", "msg: "+inMsg);
          Log.w("params", url);
          JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(inMsg);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.w("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getInt("Id")

                    );

                    //Get an output to the screen
                    //return String += "\n\t" + jArray.getJSONObject(i); 
            }
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: did you wrote the server?

Comment: is this Log.w("params", "msg: "+inMsg); statement shows blank response?

Comment: I'm using free web hosting server AWARDSPACE. I uploaded php file on server, that responds to specific variable, or returns "Wrong variable" answer

Comment: DeepSan:
It shows default answer "Wrong variable"

Comment: Could you post the php code?

Comment: Here is my php code:
        <?php
include("xxx");
$table='';
  
  if(isset($_GET['retrieve'])){
  $table = $_GET['retrieve'];
  // in this part i fetch data from sql db and show output as json
     print(json_encode($output));
  }else{
  
    echo mysql_error ();
   print("Error retrieving data from db");
  }
  }else{
  
  echo "Wrong variable";
  }
 
  

?>

Comment: You need to use $_POST instead of $_GET.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, but i just found answer to my own problem, the problem was i set GET method in php instead POST. Should use REQUEST instead

Comment: Your right Torben Kohlmeier, problem was in GET method

Comment: Thanks everyone for help and quick response.