# Send Form-data Post request using Http Post in android

Tags: android, http-post

I want to send an HTTP Post request using 'form-data'. Here is a screenshot of the rest-client to show what do i want:

[image]

**More Information related to headers:**

```
POST /action HTTP/1.1
Host: requsrt-utl
Cache-Control: no-cache

----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"

abc@gmail.com
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

123456
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
```

I tried using [UrlEncodedFormEntity](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/entity/UrlEncodedFormEntity.html) but it is setting the content-type as 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' which is not correct.

My Android Code:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urlStr);
        try {
            UrlEncodedFormEntity encodedFormEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs);
            httppost.setEntity(encodedFormEntity);
            HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            return httpresponse.getEntity().getContent();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

When i am using this, web-service is not getting any parameter and hence it sending a message that 'parameters are absent'.

Please help!

Answer (score 5):

This may help you

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urlStr);

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);  

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", "12312"));  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sessionid", "234"));  

httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

[how to add parameters in android http post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288823/how-to-add-parameters-in-android-http-post)

Comment: I am doing same but always getting '415 unsupported media' type. I am not even setting any content-type header.

Comment: you may need to set the header 'Content-Type'. `request.addHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");`

Comment: Content header was not needed. They created a multi-part http call, So I made that.