# Large data is not sending in android through webservice

Tags: java, android, web-services, http, http-post

I am using the following code in android to send data to a server through a web service 
call.When i am sending small amount of data it is hitting the server.When i am sending large data it is not hitting the server.Simply it is httpClient.execute(httpPost); .But i am not getting any result.What might be the problem

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url+data);

httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

if (rsopnse != null)
   System.out.println(httpPost.getMethod());
try
{

     httpResponse= httpClient.execute(httpPost);

}catch(Exception e)
{
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `List<NameValuePair>` for all the parameters that you want to pass in the Request. You should not append your parameters to the URL, which is more of the GET style of making a call.

The examples for HTTP Post are covered in the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288823/how-to-add-parameters-in-android-http-post).

Comment: is there any problem like what i used ?