# Send multiple values httpPost from android to WCF service

Tags: android, wcf, web-services

The question could seems silly but I don't want to do a mistake.
As explained in the title, I want to send multiple fields to a WS using post method. To be simple, a title (a string), and an image.
So far, I have succedded into sending the image (after A LOT of troubles).

Here is the android code:

```
String urlServer = GlobalSession.IP + "insert_reportByte";
            URL url = new URL(urlServer);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);

            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","multipart/form-data");

            DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(
                    connection.getOutputStream());

            outputStream.write(outputByteArray, 0, outputByteArray.length);
            Log.d("Report", " Amount of data sent for the picture: " + outputByteArray.length);

            int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
```

that is sucessfuly sending the picture (outputByteArray) the the following WS:

```
public void insert_reportByte(Stream input) 
    {
        MyEntities entities = new MyEntities();

        byte[] image = new byte[30*1024];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = input.Read(image, 0, image.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(image, 0, read);
            }
        }

        String base64stringimage = System.Convert.ToBase64String(image,0,image.Length);
        entities.insert_report("name hard coded", base64stringimage);
    }
```

So, I want to switch from that delcaration to `public void insert_reportByte(String name, Stream input)`. How to do so? Or do I have to send everything in the stream an then recovering one by one the parameters transmitted?

Thanks for tips!

Answer (score 1):

Look like your problem is handle [Multipart data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4526286/719212) request. 
For the android client side, you could look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5220954/719212), there is a `MultipartEntity` which is multipart/form coded HTTP entity consisting of multiple body parts. Your request implement  look like this:

```
   HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urlServer);
    MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);  
    multipartEntity.addPart("name", new StringBody("your input name here"));
    multipartEntity.addPart("Image", new FileBody(new File(imagePath)));
    httppost.setEntity(multipartEntity);
    mHttpClient.execute(httppost);
```

And from the server side, you method just needs only one stream parameter. But you need to parse this stream in difference way.[Here](http://lfhck.com/question/347247/reading-file-input-from-a-multipartform-data-post) is an example which is use [form parser library](https://bitbucket.org/lorenzopolidori/http-form-parser/src). Therefore, your method should look like:

```
public void insert_reportByte(Stream stream)
{
   HttpMultipartParser parser = new HttpMultipartParser(data, "Image");

if (parser.Success)
{
    // get the name from android client
    string name = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(parser.Parameters["name"]);

    // Save the file somewhere
    File.WriteAllBytes(your_server_file_path, parser.FileContents);
}
}
```

Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add NameValue pairs in your request like this!

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, "myName"));    
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

I hope it will help! See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288823/how-to-add-parameters-in-android-http-post) answer!